# SonarQube Web server startup failed

Tags: sonarqube

SonarQube web server startup failed due to Unable to start database. Please check the below error logs and suggest how to fix this issue?

SonarQube Version - sonarqube 8.9.0.43852

It was running from last 6 months but before some days it have automatically stopped.

I have changed the java also but it is failed. previously i have used "jdk-14.0.1" but now i have changed with zulu-11 for testing but unable to start sonarqbe.

sonar.log:-

```
--> Wrapper Started as Console
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2021.12.02 00:01:40 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory C:\sonarqube-8_9_0_43852\temp
2021.12.02 00:01:40 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on [HTTP: 127.0.0.1:9001, TCP: 127.0.0.1:30038]
2021.12.02 00:01:40 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [C:\sonarqube-8_9_0_43852\elasticsearch]: C:\Zulu\zulu-11\bin\java -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\sonarqube-8_9_0_43852\temp -XX:ErrorFile=../logs/es_hs_err_pid%p.log -Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60 -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10 -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -Xss1m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0 -Dio.netty.allocator.numDirectArenas=0 -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true -Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT -Xmx2048m -Xms1024m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=256m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Delasticsearch -Des.path.home=C:\sonarqube-8_9_0_43852\elasticsearch -Des.path.conf=C:\sonarqube-8_9_0_43852\temp\conf\es -cp lib/* org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch
2021.12.02 00:01:40 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
2021.12.02 00:01:53 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is up
2021.12.02 00:01:53 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='web', ipcIndex=2, logFilenamePrefix=web]] from [C:\sonarqube-8_9_0_43852]: C:\Zulu\zulu-11\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\sonarqube-8_9_0_43852\temp -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED -Xmx2048m -Xms1024m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -javaagent:./extensions/plugins/sonarqube-community-branch-plugin-1.8.0.jar=web -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.*|[::1] -cp ./lib/sonar-application-8.9.0.43852.jar;C:\sonarqube-8_9_0_43852\lib\jdbc\h2\h2-1.4.199.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer C:\sonarqube-8_9_0_43852\temp\sq-process7692807252093486043properties
00:01:54.193 [main] INFO com.github.mc1arke.sonarqube.plugin.CommunityBranchAgent - Loading agent
```

web.log:-

```
2021.12.02 00:01:54 INFO  web[][o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting web
2021.12.02 00:01:55 INFO  web[][o.a.t.u.n.NioSelectorPool] Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
2021.12.02 00:01:57 INFO  web[][o.s.c.e.CoreExtensionsLoader] Loaded core extensions: Community Branch Plugin
2021.12.02 00:01:57 INFO  web[][o.s.s.e.EsClientProvider] Connected to local Elasticsearch: [http://127.0.0.1:9001]
2021.12.02 00:01:57 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.LogServerVersion] SonarQube Server / 8.9.0.43852 / 681d1975f698b70fc4e981593f7bed298ff2f60d
2021.12.02 00:02:06 ERROR web[][o.s.s.p.PlatformImpl] Web server startup failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to start database
    at org.sonar.server.platform.db.EmbeddedDatabase.startServer(EmbeddedDatabase.java:87)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.db.EmbeddedDatabase.start(EmbeddedDatabase.java:62)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.db.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory.start(EmbeddedDatabaseFactory.java:49)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.StartableCloseableSafeLifecyleStrategy.start(StartableCloseableSafeLifecyleStrategy.java:40)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1016)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1009)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:767)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:136)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevel.start(PlatformLevel.java:90)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevel1.start(PlatformLevel1.java:166)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformImpl.start(PlatformImpl.java:213)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformImpl.startLevel1Container(PlatformImpl.java:172)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformImpl.init(PlatformImpl.java:86)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.PlatformServletContextListener.contextInitialized(PlatformServletContextListener.java:43)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5171)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1402)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientConnectionException: File corrupted while reading record: null. Possible solution: use the recovery tool [90030-199]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:617)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:427)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:194)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTableEngine$Store.convertIllegalStateException(MVTableEngine.java:205)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTableEngine$Store.open(MVTableEngine.java:173)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTableEngine.init(MVTableEngine.java:95)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.getPageStore(Database.java:2739)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.open(Database.java:769)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.openDatabase(Database.java:319)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.<init>(Database.java:313)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:69)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:201)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:178)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:161)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:31)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:336)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:169)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:148)
    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:69)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:251)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.db.EmbeddedDatabase.createDatabase(EmbeddedDatabase.java:114)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.db.EmbeddedDatabase.startServer(EmbeddedDatabase.java:78)
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: File corrupted in chunk 40000, expected page length 4..3072, got 976435508 [1.4.199/6]
    at org.h2.mvstore.DataUtils.newIllegalStateException(DataUtils.java:883)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.readBufferForPage(MVStore.java:1055)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.readPage(MVStore.java:2186)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVMap.readPage(MVMap.java:554)
    at org.h2.mvstore.Page$NonLeaf.getChildPage(Page.java:1086)
    at org.h2.mvstore.Cursor.hasNext(Cursor.java:53)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.readStoreHeader(MVStore.java:793)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.<init>(MVStore.java:401)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore$Builder.open(MVStore.java:3343)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTableEngine$Store.open(MVTableEngine.java:162)
    ... 44 common frames omitted
2021.12.02 00:02:06 WARN  web[][o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase] The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [pool-2-thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:\n java.base@11.0.13/sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll0(Native Method)\n java.base@11.0.13/sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:357)\n java.base@11.0.13/sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.doSelect(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:182)\n java.base@11.0.13/sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:124)\n java.base@11.0.13/sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:136)\n app//org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.execute(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:343)\n app//org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.execute(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:221)\n app//org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase$1.run(CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase.java:64)\n java.base@11.0.13/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
2021.12.02 00:02:06 WARN  web[][o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase] The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [I/O dispatcher 1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:\n java.base@11.0.13/sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll0(Native Method)\n java.base@11.0.13/sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:357)\n java.base@11.0.13/sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.doSelect(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:182)\n java.base@11.0.13/sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:124)\n java.base@11.0.13/sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:136)\n app//org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:255)\n app//org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)\n app//org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:591)\n java.base@11.0.13/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
2021.12.02 00:02:06 WARN  web[][o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase] The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [I/O dispatcher 2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:\n java.base@11.0.13/sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll0(Native Method)\n java.base@11.0.13/sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:357)\n java.base@11.0.13/sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.doSelect(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:182)\n java.base@11.0.13/sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:124)\n java.base@11.0.13/sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:136)\n app//org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:255)\n app//org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)\n app//org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:591)\n java.base@11.0.13/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
2021.12.02 00:02:06 WARN  web[][o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase] The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [I/O dispatcher 3] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:\n java.base@11.0.13/sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll0(Native Method)\n java.base@11.0.13/sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:357)\n java.base@11.0.13/sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.doSelect(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:182)\n java.base@11.0.13/sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:124)\n java.base@11.0.13/sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:136)\n app//org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:255)\n app//org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)\n app//org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:591)\n java.base@11.0.13/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
2021.12.02 00:02:06 WARN  web[][o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase] The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [I/O dispatcher 4] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:\n java.base@11.0.13/sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll0(Native Method)\n java.base@11.0.13/sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:357)\n java.base@11.0.13/sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.doSelect(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:182)\n java.base@11.0.13/sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:124)\n java.base@11.0.13/sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:136)\n app//org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:255)\n app//org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)\n app//org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:591)\n java.base@11.0.13/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
2021.12.02 00:02:06 INFO  web[][o.s.s.a.EmbeddedTomcat] HTTP connector enabled on port 9000
2021.12.02 00:02:06 INFO  web[][o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Hard stopping process
```

es.lo:-

```
2021.12.02 00:01:44 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] version[7.12.1], pid[11488], build[unknown/unknown/3186837139b9c6b6d23c3200870651f10d3343b7/2021-04-20T20:56:39.040728659Z], OS[Windows Server 2012 R2/6.3/amd64], JVM[Azul Systems, Inc./OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/11.0.13/11.0.13+8-LTS]
2021.12.02 00:01:44 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] JVM home [C:\Zulu\zulu-11]
2021.12.02 00:01:44 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] JVM arguments [-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\sonarqube-8_9_0_43852\temp, -XX:ErrorFile=../logs/es_hs_err_pid%p.log, -Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60, -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dio.netty.allocator.numDirectArenas=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT, -Xmx2048m, -Xms1024m, -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=256m, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Delasticsearch, -Des.path.home=C:\sonarqube-8_9_0_43852\elasticsearch, -Des.path.conf=C:\sonarqube-8_9_0_43852\temp\conf\es]
2021.12.02 00:01:45 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [analysis-common]
2021.12.02 00:01:45 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [lang-painless]
2021.12.02 00:01:45 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [parent-join]
2021.12.02 00:01:45 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [percolator]
2021.12.02 00:01:45 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [transport-netty4]
2021.12.02 00:01:45 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no plugins loaded
2021.12.02 00:01:45 INFO  es[][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment] using [1] data paths, mounts [[System (C:)]], net usable_space [43.5gb], net total_space [179.9gb], types [NTFS]
2021.12.02 00:01:45 INFO  es[][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment] heap size [1.9gb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
2021.12.02 00:01:45 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] node name [sonarqube], node ID [VZI_EdJ6Shi73Sn5jxlMlA], cluster name [sonarqube], roles [master, remote_cluster_client, data, ingest]
2021.12.02 00:01:48 INFO  es[][o.e.t.NettyAllocator] creating NettyAllocator with the following configs: [name=elasticsearch_configured, chunk_size=1mb, suggested_max_allocation_size=1mb, factors={es.unsafe.use_netty_default_chunk_and_page_size=false, g1gc_enabled=false, g1gc_region_size=0b}]
2021.12.02 00:01:48 INFO  es[][o.e.d.DiscoveryModule] using discovery type [zen] and seed hosts providers [settings]
2021.12.02 00:01:49 INFO  es[][o.e.g.DanglingIndicesState] gateway.auto_import_dangling_indices is disabled, dangling indices will not be automatically detected or imported and must be managed manually
2021.12.02 00:01:49 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] initialized
2021.12.02 00:01:49 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] starting ...
2021.12.02 00:01:49 INFO  es[][o.e.t.TransportService] publish_address {127.0.0.1:30038}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:30038}
2021.12.02 00:01:49 WARN  es[][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks] initial heap size [1073741824] not equal to maximum heap size [2147483648]; this can cause resize pauses
2021.12.02 00:01:49 INFO  es[][o.e.c.c.Coordinator] cluster UUID [N8ezl7IhQB-UNxLM8A312w]
2021.12.02 00:01:49 INFO  es[][o.e.c.s.MasterService] elected-as-master ([1] nodes joined)[{sonarqube}{VZI_EdJ6Shi73Sn5jxlMlA}{K2U-O33MSP6U9Q0ZPRE0vw}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:30038}{dimr}{rack_id=sonarqube} elect leader, _BECOME_MASTER_TASK_, _FINISH_ELECTION_], term: 30, version: 882, delta: master node changed {previous [], current [{sonarqube}{VZI_EdJ6Shi73Sn5jxlMlA}{K2U-O33MSP6U9Q0ZPRE0vw}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:30038}{dimr}{rack_id=sonarqube}]}
2021.12.02 00:01:50 INFO  es[][o.e.c.s.ClusterApplierService] master node changed {previous [], current [{sonarqube}{VZI_EdJ6Shi73Sn5jxlMlA}{K2U-O33MSP6U9Q0ZPRE0vw}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:30038}{dimr}{rack_id=sonarqube}]}, term: 30, version: 882, reason: Publication{term=30, version=882}
2021.12.02 00:01:50 INFO  es[][o.e.h.AbstractHttpServerTransport] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9001}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9001}
2021.12.02 00:01:50 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] started
2021.12.02 00:01:50 INFO  es[][o.e.g.GatewayService] recovered [7] indices into cluster_state
2021.12.02 00:01:53 INFO  es[][o.e.c.r.a.AllocationService] Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [GREEN] (reason: [shards started [[components][2]]]).
```